Word VSTO ThisAddin class errors
I have dozens of errors in the generated file ThisAddinDesigner.vb and don't know what caused them. The operational symptom is that 'Application' is not a member of 'ThisAddIn' wherever this is relied on in my code (yet the corresponding code files are not shown in the error list). There are so many errors it's more practical to screenshot the list than enter them here. This is not a new project, it's a year old now and has been fine until today. I have cleared out all my own code in ThisAddIn, to no avail. Can anyone advise how to either diagnose the problem, or regenerate the class instance?
Although ThisAddIn.Designer.vb is a generated file, the project won't build if I remove it. Cleaning and rebuilding makes no difference; cleaning does not remove the file.
ThisAddIn.Designer.vb errors:
(https://i.sstatic.net/CfPT5brk.png)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In the below line in the generated file ThisAddIn.Designer.vb, the space between Class and ThisAddIn had been lost. Strange as I have never opened this file, nor even knew of it before the errors appeared. But it all works now.
Partial Public NotInheritable Class ThisAddIn

You are allowed to tick it
